# what is the difference between PROVISIONING_PROFILE in build settings and adhoc package process?

Tags: ios

This question confuse me a lot.
what is the difference between PROVISIONING_PROFILE in build settings and adhoc package process?

I try to archive my app by using adhoc to make my .ipa file. then it notice me to choose  PROVISIONING_PROFILE. I want to know what it is and what is different from PROVISIONING_PROFILE in my build settings.

I don't know if someone have the same confuse with me. I've search it for a long time...

Answer (score 0):

To archive app for adhoc users follow these steps

1) go to developer.apple.com member centre

2) select certificate, provisioning profile section

3) first create a certificate in adhoc distribution mode download it and double click it it will open keychain access and will show your certificate.

4) create your app id in app id section with the same package name as in your project

5) add device in device section with its uuid on which you want to run this application

6) then create provisioning profile from provisioning profile section select certificate add app id which you have created just now

7) select for adhoc distribution while selecting type of profile

8) download it and double click, it will get added in yur xcode.

9) after that you can select that particular profile in your build setting then archive it and select distribution.

10) in distribution you can select the second option which is for adhoc distribution. it will create ipa file.

11) send ipa file and provisional profile which you had just downloaded to the person whose uuid you selected while generating profile.

12) he/she will require to put both the file on  on iTunes and sync his iPhone with that to get application on his phone

Comment: I found an article about the provisioning profile re-sign. It tells me  on xcode4+ we can choose an other provisioning profile after archive and it provisioning profile is the real use of the app.http://oleb.net/blog/2011/06/code-signing-changes-in-xcode-4/